# Implement method only in iOS 8 and above

Tags: ios

I'd like to implement `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` but only in iOS 7 and below.

What is the appropriate compile-time directive to use so that my tableViews won't call this method if the app is running on iOS8?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this?

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0

#else

#endif
```